# How to set hour and minute using javascript for plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, set, hour

Hi i am trying to give fix hours and minutes to the html view trying to modify the plugin but having issue with changes

This is my plugin code

```
(function ($) {
$.extend($.ui, { timepicker: { version: "0.3.3"} });
var PROP_NAME = 'timepicker',
tpuuid = new Date().getTime();
```

And Now i am tring to set the default hour default to **Zero(0)** and the minute to the **30** How can i do that...?
this is what i have tried:

```
tpuuid = new Date().getTime();
tpuuid.setHours(0);
tpuuid.setMinutes(30);
```

but is is saying like `tpuuid` is not a funtion... how can resolve this isssue.. thanks for help.

**THIS IS PLUGIN SOURCE :** [CLICK HERE TO SEE THE PLUGIN](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code From

```
tpuuid = new Date().getTime();
tpuuid.setHours(0);
tpuuid.setMinutes(30);
```

to

```
tpuuid = new Date();
tpuuid.setHours(0);
tpuuid.setMinutes(30);
```

Comment: Not working brother still same issue it is taking my local computer hour and minute

Comment: if you will use `new Date()` then it will return local computer time.

Comment: then how can i resolve this i just want to set default time to `zero hour` and `30 minutes`